# Are normed spaces isodyne?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cardinals

In general, do all non-empty open subsets of a normed space necessarily have the same cardinality?

Comment: This is true for all basic open neighbourhoods of a point, as these are all homeomorphic.

Comment: but the whole space can actually be larger?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi:B(0,1) \to X$ be given by $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} \tan (\|x\| { \pi \over 2 }){x \over \|x\|}, & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x=0 \end{cases}$. We see that $\phi^{-1} (x) = \begin{cases} {2 \over \pi}\arctan (\|x\| ){x \over \|x\|}, & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x=0 \end{cases}$, hence $\phi$ is a bijection.

Hence
$\operatorname{card} B(0,1) = \operatorname{card} X$.

If $r>0$, the map $x \mapsto x_0+rx$ is invertible, hence $\operatorname{card} B(x_0,r) = \operatorname{card} B(0,1)$.

If $U$ is open, we have $B(x_0,r) \subset U$ for some $x_0,r$, and so
$\operatorname{card} X = \operatorname{card} B(x_0,r) \le \operatorname{card} U \le \operatorname{card} X$.

It follows that all open sets have the same cardinality as $X$.

Comment: OK, this I easier than I thought :) do you perhaps happen to know what conditions are needed for general metric spaces?

Comment: Not offhand. It is not true in general metric spaces, of course. Take $(0,1) \cup \{2\}$ with the usual $\mathbb{R}$ metric. Then $\{2\}$ and $(0,1)$ are open but do not have the same cardinality.